# How to map decimal (30,6) from database to C# in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, decimal

I have a COMPUTED FIELD in MS database that is from [decimal(10,2)*money], which make the field to be decimal(30,6). I could not map this to a decimal or double in C#. Does anybody have solution?

Thanks

Comment: A .NET `decimal` can hold values from ±1.0 × 10 ^ −28 to ±7.9 × 10 ^ 28. AFAIK a DB `decimal(30, 6)` type means it has 24 digits to the left and 6 digits to the right of the decimal point. So the .NET decimal type should be enough...

Comment: Well, the range doesn't mean precision (number of effective digits). The solution for me is to not use it by trimming down the precision a little bit, kind of a concede on business side. Welcome if anybody has better tech solution

Comment: I know this is old but it may be related to bug I discovered which limits decimal columns to use a precision of 28. I raised a bug on [MS connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1094658).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't indicated what kind of error you are getting and what exactly you are attempting, but I would suggest that you try setting `Precision` and `Scale` properties on the decimal field to 30 and 6 correspondingly. (In the EF designer right-click the decimal field, choose properties and set the values in the Properties window).

Comment: Yes, your guess is right. I can set the decimal in EF designer, but when the program has a run time error saying the C# decimal cannot take it and overflow....